# Generating a python library from c++ for android (arm) - maybe with swig?

Tags: python, android, c++, kivy, python-for-android

I want to include a c++-library in my [kivy](https://kivy.org/) python app. It is possible to automatically do that with [swig](https://swig.org/Doc4.1/Python.html#) and [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html), which effectively generates a .pyd python library out of the c++ code.  On windows that works without any problems: I included the .pyd file in my Kivy app and everything runs, but I want to run the program on mobile devices as well.

So my problem is how I can generate a python library which is compatible with android (arm) and includes the c++-code I need.

[I already asked a different question about how I can cross-compile python code for arm on windows x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072712/creating-a-python-library-for-use-in-android). There someone recommended [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com). That seems to work, but of course only with python as source code, not with c++.

For the library creation process with swig and distutils I created a 'setup.py' which takes the output from swig and builds the .pyd library. Is it possible to modify that to compile for arm?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
setup.py file for SWIG
"""

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


example_module = Extension('_HelloCpp',
                           sources=['HelloCpp_wrap.cxx', 'HelloCpp.cpp'],
                           extra_compile_args = ["-std:c++17"]
                           )

setup (name = 'HelloCpp',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "simonsays",
       description = """Simple swig test with HelloCpp""",
       ext_modules = [example_module],
       py_modules = ["HelloCpp"],
       )
```

I also stumbled over this Github repository: [Virtual Environments for Cross-Compiling Python Extension Modules](https://github.com/benfogle/crossenv). Do I need that to compile Python for Android or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

To include a C++ library in an Android Kivy app, you'll need to define a compilation recipe. For details, see the [python-for-android documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/), and the list of [existing recipes](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes).